# What is NULL doing in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

So I am looking through a bit of code in an Oracle (PLSQL) stored procedure and I came across something that I don't understand.

```
  if lv_var1= ' ' then
     null;
  else
     begin.....
```

It's simply the line that says *null*

What does it do (If anything).

My guess is that it exists out of the whole procedure but I can't find any information on it.

Comment: It's a [`NULL` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/null_statement.htm#LNPLS01330).

Comment: It really does just mean 'do nothing'.  It can be useful in the dev phase (you may want to check your code compiles before you've coded logic in all branches of your IF statement) and also it can useful as a signpost that you recognise a condition is possible but you want to do no work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't do anything. In PLSQL you can't have an empty condition, doing something like this simply wouldn't compile:

```
if lv_var1= ' ' then
  --do nothing
else
    begin.....`
```

By having null there the condition is not empty, so the procedure compiles but nothing happens if that branch is ever reached.

It could probably be written as this instead:

```
if lv_var1 != ' ' then
  begin...
end if;
```

Edit: As Boneist correctly pointed out, the above alternative doesn't take into account null values, this could either be done with an nvl e.g. `nvl(lv_var1,'empty') != ' '` or an `OR` condition e.g. `lv_var1 != ' ' OR lv_var1 IS NULL`

Comment: It could only be rewritten in the second form if lv_var1 is not null. You'd have to change it to include nulls (most likely via an NVL).

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it's useful purely from an informational perspective. As Boneist correctly pointed out, the alternative I suggested wouldn't have worked if the value was null, so the answer has been updated accordingly.